# Minimizing sum of maximum of functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Assume that $x$ is a vector and we have a set of affine functions $f_i(x)$, $i=1,\ldots,N$, and $g_j(x)$, $j=1,\ldots,M$. We want to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\min_x &\Big(\max_{i=1,\ldots,N} f_i(x) + \max_{j=1,\ldots,M} g_j(x) \Big) \\
& Cx \leq d
\end{align}
where $C$ and $d$ are a matrix and a vector with appropriate dimensions. How can we solve this? Assume that we can evaluate the values of functions but it is not easy to compute the derivations of functions analytically. Any idea is appreciated.

What I know is that if $g_j(x)=0$, $j=1,\ldots,M$, then the above optimization is equivalent to the following LP:

\begin{align}
\min_{x,z} \quad &z  \\
& Cx \leq d \\
&z \geq f_i(x), \quad i=1,\ldots,N.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you try:
\begin{align}
&\underset{x,z,v}{\text{minimize}}\quad z+v \\
&\text{subject to} \\
&Cx\leq d\\
&z\geq f_i(x),\quad i=1,\dots,N\\
&v\geq g_i(x), \quad j=1,\dots,M
\end{align}

Comment: I think this gives us an upper-bound on the cost because $z+v \geq \max_{i=1,\ldots,N} f_i(x) + \max_{j=1,\ldots,M} g_j(x) $  and hence, $\min_{x,z,v}z+v \geq \min_x \big(\max_{i=1,\ldots,N} f_i(x) + \max_{j=1,\ldots,M} g_j(x) \big)$.

Comment: @m0_as the bound is tight. $z$ and $v$ are not further constrained, so it must be the case that at least one of the $N$ and $M$ inequalities, respectively, is tight at the optimum. Ture is correct here.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Let me say what I got from your comment:"at the optimal solution, at least one of $N$ equalities and one of $M$ equalities should be tight; otherwise we can decrease the objective function by making $z$ and $v$ tight." Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.